# HTML email not received in gmail, but succeeds with yahoo, msn, aim, and work domain. Is it my HTML?

Tags: html, gmail, newsletter, html-email

I have tried sending and HTML formatted email using ACYmailing for Joomla AND Mailchimp. It works for yahoo, msn, aim, my work domain but not for gmail.

I can send plain emails from my server to gmail but the HTML formatted newsletter doesn't work.

Someone suggested it may be my HTML code ~~~> [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/m5e8cd39b)

I couldn't find a problem with it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "doesn't work"?  Do you see just plain text, HTML but no images, does the message not get through, or do you see an error of some sort?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean it doesn't show up at all in the inbox or spam folder.

Comment: OMG I feel like such a newb! I didn't know gmail was hiding the spam label. I have been looking in the "Junk E-mail" label that outlook created. The messages were in my "Spam" label that gmail hide. So to me it would appear the messages were not coming at all. I would check junk email thinking that was the spam folder. Now I just have to figure out why it's going to the spam folder. I apologize for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Maybe GMail recognizes it as spam. Try some different content
- Did you set the headers of the email correctly?
- Did you specify a correct sender / sender name?

Answer (score 1):

Are you receiving a rejection or failed email response?  If it is being rejected you should get an email explaining why which will be sent (although you will need to specify a correct from / reply-to email address to receive this).

The first thing I would check is if the IP you are sending from has been blacklisted by any spam services - most deliverability issues I have experienced have been due to this.  You can check a fairly extensive list of spam blacklists (together with some additional email validation services) at [MX Toolbox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)

If everything appears fine there it may be due to Gmail's fairly strict antispam criteria.  To be accepted, an email should contain in the headers a valid email address for `Return-Path`.  If this is not valid then there must be a `Reply-To` header with a valid email address.

Another important weapon in Googles antispam arsenal is [SPF record](http://www.openspf.org/) checking - essentially a way of validating that an IP address is authorised to send email for a particular domain.  This is worth checking however as far as I am aware a missing SPF record will only cause the mail to go into spam rather than not be delivered.

Comment: The emails are not being delivered at all. I don't received a rejectrion or failed attempt from gmail. The ip isn't blacklisted as I'm able to send a normal text email from my server to gmail. I have checked. Mailchimp a very big ESP seems to be having the same issue. I've tried sending from my server and mailchimps server both with the same results.

Comment: Could you try with a simpler HTML mail rather than the one you currently are using? a simple table with no inline styles should work (as long as it validates)

Answer (score 1):

Gmail has three tabs now, especially if you're part of their partner network. I encountered the same issue until I noticed the three tabs. They are "Primary", "Social", and "Promotions". All of my MailChimp email wound up under the Promotions tab. Check there for your emails from MailChimp and possibly other e-blast emails. I don't have the solution yet on how to get MailChimp emails to go directly to the Primary area of the inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're actually sending the HTML you reference in your question, note that it's invalid - you haven't wrapped it in the necessary `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

I realize it's likely you just forgot to include those tags in the pastebin reference, but just in case.  Note that the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org) found several (minor) errors in the referenced fragment.

Comment: Michael I see what you mean. duly noted